# Conditional Account Constraint on Anchor

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is there a way I can have an Account Constraint in the Accounts struct for Anchor which only checks when NOT on localnet?

I would like to check whether a given mint account actually has a specified key (for eg. USDC) but while testing on localnet, I don't require this check?

Answer (score 3):

This snippet from the Anchor [`tests` directory](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/6baed77eb57d41455a5f3c1e026d86da756d1c8e/tests/cfo/programs/cfo/src/lib.rs#L369) does the trick,

```
#[cfg_attr(
    not(feature = "test"),
    account(address = mint::SRM),
)]
srm_mint: Box<Account<'info, Mint>>,
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test your program to the fullest, the best thing to do would just be to clone the accounts you'd need to reference on to localnet. With Anchor tests in particular, the way to do this would be to add a few lines to your `Anchor.toml` file (copied from the Anchor docs):

```
[test.validator]
url = "https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"

[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "7NL2qWArf2BbEBBH1vTRZCsoNqFATTddH6h8GkVvrLpG"
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "2RaN5auQwMdg5efgCaVqpETBV8sacWGR8tkK4m9kjo5r"
[[test.validator.clone]]
address = "metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s" # implicitly also clones PwDiXFxQsGra4sFFTT8r1QWRMd4vfumiWC1jfWNfdYT
```

This is from the [test-validator](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/manifest#test-validator) section of the Anchor book. The other config options are explained in more detail there.

When I do my local tests I actually do them with [Amman CLI](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/amman/blob/master/amman/README.md) and the Amman Explorer (https://amman-explorer.metaplex.com) from Metaplex (it makes it easier to see account changes in real time). Amman has similar options to clone accounts, and you can pass in `--ignore-test-validator` to `anchor test` to default to the already running test validator that you started with Amman.